# using getchar() function to pause program but something's wrong with it

Tags: c++, getchar

I tried to using getchar() function to pause program when user enters 'm' or 'M'.

The main problem is I don't know why I can't use :

```
while (check != 'm' || check != 'M' );
```

Instead of:

```
while (check != 'm' && check != 'M' );
```

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int month, check;
    
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the number, press 'm' or 'M' to exit. \n";
        cin >> month;

        check = getchar();
        switch(month)
        {
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 12:
            {
                cout << "Winter. \n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (check != 'm' && check != 'M' ); // It works
    while (check != 'm' || check != 'M' ); // It doesn't

    return 0; 

}
```

I'm newbie so pls help me.

Comment: I don't think you should be using `cin` and `getchar()` at the same time. Choose one.

Comment: `while (check != 'm' || check != 'M' )` will always be `true` (because `check` will never be equal to both `m` and `M`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (check != 'm' || check != 'M' );
```

is nonsense because the condition will always be true assuming that `'m'` and `'M'` have different values.

When `check` equals to `'m'`, it is not equal to `'M'`, so `check != 'M'` is true and the condition is true.

When `check` doesn't equal to `'m'`, `check != 'm'` is true, so the condition is true.

Comment: tks, finally I know why